# Proper ADAL’s AuthenticationContext life cycle management in WebJobs long running processes

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, adal

I have an Azure WebJob that runs in continues run mode. The main WebJob’s process can run for a long period of time, potentially, months since it runs in continues mode.

I like to confirm the proper way of instantiating AuthenticationContext in the process.

- Option1: instantiate an instance of AuthenticationContext in the Main() method and use it for the duration of the WebJob process – can be a few month
- Option 2: Upon any need for an OAUTH Bearer token instantiate an instance of AuthenticationContext and get the token.

I am thinking to use the Option 1. But I wanted to confirm my approach here.
This question can apply to Windows Services scenarios as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference to develop Active Directory Authentication Library with other libraries.

Both two options should work, it depends on your requirements. For example, if use the option1, then the object will always in the memory. And if you use the option2, since it will initialize the instance every time need, so it may slight slow than option1. In a normal environment, there is little difference bebwteen these two options.

You may test yourself to see whether you can accept which one.

Comment: Option2 imposes a heavy cost of getting a Berear token through a REST call every time you instantiate an  AuthenticationContext. with Option 1, AuthenticationContext  caches the Berear token and handles refresh token scenarios quite efficiently. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the option2 will get the access token via HTTP request every time since the instance of `AuthenticationContext` will be created every time.

Comment: And based on my understanding, if you use the **client credentials flow**, the library will not help us to refresh the access token since there is no refresh token in this scenario. It do cache the access token, however in the scenario, you can get the access token after call the `AcquireTokenAsync(string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential)`, then we can use this access token directly. And after the access token is expired, we can call that method to retrieve a new access token.